# how to stop printing result again and again. So how to stop getting value again and again

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatttool

```
import gatt

class AnyDeviceManager(gatt.Device):
    def device_discovered(self,device):
        print("Discovered [%s] %s" % (device.mac_address,device.alias()))
    
manager = AnyDeviceManager(adapter_name='hci0')
manager.start_discovery()
manager.run()
```

how to stop printing results again and again. So how do stop getting value again and again

Comment: Is your question, how to stop discovery?  Or is it that you only want to print a device once?

Comment: just want list of device once

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you need to track which devices have already been discovered.

There are different ways to do this depending what you want to do with the information.

One example would be:

```py
class AnyDeviceManager(gatt.Device):
    device = {}

    def device_discovered(self, device):
        if device.mac_address not in AnyDeviceManager.device:
            print("Discovered [%s] %s" % (device.mac_address, device.alias()))
            AnyDeviceManager.device[device.mac_address] = device
```